# how to compile this java application

Tags: java, c

I need to compile the Java app from this code on Windows:

http://www.falstad.com/vector3dm/base.java

The comments at the to mention that

```
// this file must be run through cpp with one of BUILD_E, BUILD_V,
// BUILD_M defined before compiling with java compiler.  This was done
// to reduce class file sizes.
```

I don't know what it means. Does cpp stands for C++ compiler? How do I run it on this java code?
I see some #define statments in the code.
Being a Java code I would expected 'javac base.java' to just work

Can someone please explain what I need to do in order to compile the code.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

@Ahmed Masaud:
I downloaded anarres-cpp-bin-1.2.6.tar.gz from the annarres website and extracted in my JDK directory. 
Here is what I have now:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\base.java

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\anarres-cpp.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\gnu.getopt.jar

When running the command you indicated

> java -Xmx128M -cp lib/anarres-cpp.jar:lib/gnu.getopt.jar
>   org.anarres.cpp.Main -o base-e.java -DBUILD_E base.java

and here is what I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/anarres/cpp/Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.anarres.cpp.Main
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: org.anarres.cpp.Main.  Program will exit.

it looks like it can't find 'org.anarres.cpp.Main'

Comment: [3 ways to resolve NoClassDefFoundError](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPP means C-preprocessor not C++. What they are asking you to do is to run it with a particular define:

If you are using linux you can do this by typing

```
  cpp -o base-e.java -DBUILD_E base.java
```

this will create a base-e.java file which uses the BUILD_E options in base.java

<strike>If you are using windows grab mcpp:</strike>

http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/download.html

and use mcpp to do the same thing.

There is an alternate jcpp which is a C pre-processor written in java:

http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/

may be better choice.

jcpp is pretty close to the GNU cpp; as it's based on it, so the command-line above should work, and a pre-compiled version is available on that site so:

<strike>java -Xmx128M -cp lib/anarres-cpp.jar:lib/gnu.getopt.jar org.anarres.cpp.Main -o base-e.java -DBUILD_E base.java</strike>

Proper command-line:

```
java -Xmx128M -cp ./lib/anarres-cpp.jar:./lib/gnu.getopt.jar: org.anarres.cpp.Main -DBUILD_E base.java > base-e.java
```

There is no -o flag support in jcpp

make sure you put base.java in the anarres-cpp-bin-1.2.6 folder and then run the above command from in there.

you can then move the base-e.java wherever you like.

alternatively you can provide full paths to base.java and base-e.java on command line etc.

Comment: you forgot to mention how to call it. also, I am on windows

Comment: can you please say what do I need to call on Windows?

Comment: its a java program, once you have java installed and in your path you can call it like the last line '    java -classpath c:\myfolder classname

Comment: or head over to google and search for starting java tutorial - how to run on windows

Comment: @Ahmed Masud: it doesn't work, can you please look to what I did, I edited my post

Comment: Ah my mistake I thought it was completely compatible, I am updating the command line so that it works properly

Comment: the generated base-e.java still starts with a C-like define: #line 1

Comment: I just removed that line and it compiled fine. it generated a bunch of  class files. I need to create a Jar file

Comment: I created Jar, had issues with security settings, I changed it to low to allow me to run it, but when running app in the web page, it says "Applet is finished" ...